# No encuentro un archivo ni con locate Ni con find

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Estaba usando un programa que me debía generar un json.
En el menú de nemo de guardar que me abre el programa. Parecía que lo estaba guardando en mi home.
Pero cuando he ido a mi home el archivo no estaba.
He utilizado de nuevo el programa para ver donde me lo había guardado.
He visto que desde hay podía ver el archivo que acababa de generar y que efectivamente estaba en home, pero no veía el resto de los archivos que debía haber en ese directorio.

Desde el menú de guardar de este programa. He podido renombrar el anterior , pero no abrir su ubicación.

Me he colocado en / y he utilizado find --name "el.json" y updadatedb  y locate el.json.

Alguna idea de donde ha podido ir a parar???

Comment: Tal vez el nombre no es exactamente el.json?  Tal vez es algo como el.json.txt?  Ha intendado buscar con grep?

Comment: Ese find debería darte error como lo estás intentando usar. Seguro que así lo probaste??? Yo probaría `find / -name el.json -print`, sin comillas y con sintaxis correcta del comando

Comment: He buscado con distintos nombres y con cosas como find -name "*partedelnombre*" es como si los hubiera guardado en otro sitio al que esos comando no tienen acceso

Answer (score 0):

updatedb es con sudo, y si despues de usar "sudo updatedb"  usas locate y no está, es porque no existe.
puedes intentar locate -i archivoquebuscas.json "-i" ignora mayusculas y minusculas, y tambien puedes intentar locate -i json , te saldran todos los archivos json que tienes en el ordenador

Comment: si , update db con sudo, pero no aparece, en serio, cuando le doy a guardar el archivo, no parece mi home.